# I want to take file text lines and put into an array to later compare the lines for duplicates

Tags: java

So my knowledge of java is very "green". What I am wanting to do is just read a file line by line, then compare a line to every other line to look for duplicates. Then repeat with the next line skipping the first line i compared to. Lastly I am going to have to compare specific lines from the text file and they DO need to match.

Here's what I have so far.

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*;
import java.io.IOException;
public class PracticeFileStuff {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filepath"));
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) !=null){
        list.add(line);
    }
        br.close();
        System.out.print(list);
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
}
```

I guess where I want to start at is assigning the lines to the arraylist so that I can do something like below. Next I was thinking for comparing the specific lines I think I'm making that part way more complicated than it is. What I need is when I check a specific line to run a different loop that actually looks for a certain line to match correctly.

Psuedo Code

```
    for(int i = 0; i <= numberLines; numberLines++){

if (!list[i].equals(list[numberLines])) {
    //keep checking
}else {
do{

}while (i = list[4] && numberLines = list[8] && list[4] == list[8]);{
    //keep checking if another line matches
}
}
}
```

I also have to compare other lines besides line 4 but I'll get to that later. Maybe this is not the method I want.

My question is how do I assign my arraylist strings integer vaules or how to compare entire strings to each other.

I know this is alot but I'm ready to learn!

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Yes I should have been more clear on the question, I'm wanting to know how to assign integer vaules to each string in my array OR how to compare Strings from an array to each other if assigning integers is not possible. I don't even know how to get a specific element with array list.

Comment: I fail to understand your question. You get the string stored at a given index using the get() method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get-int-. You test if two Strings are equal using equals(): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-

Comment: for the get method to work with a string how would I do that? Maybe I don't really understand fully how ArrayList works but I thought there should be some value assigned to the index of the ArrayList yes? I have it set string what I want to do is to make each line in a text file its own index. So it takes the entire string of a line

Comment: I want to set each line of text in a file to an index value in an array